# Can't loop through values in a hash

Tags: ruby

I am pretty new to Ruby.  I am cobbling together something like this:

```
in_msg.updateComments.map{|c| c.each} do |comment|
```

`in_msg.updateComments` is a hash.

but I get the error:

```
SyntaxError: /Users/alexgenadinik/projects/cmply/cmply-app/app/models/linked_in_update.rb:65: syntax error, unexpected kDO, expecting kEND
      in_msg.updateComments.map{|c| c.each} do |comment|
```

Any idea how to do this correctly?

The data comes in like this:

```
 "updateComments"=>{"values"=>[{"comment"=>"Sweet", "person"=>{"siteStandardProfileRequest"=>{"url"=>"http://www.linkedin.com/profile?viewProfile=&key=23676551&authToken=FHXz&authType=name&trk=api*a140290*s148640*"},
```

Comment: Are you trying to use `map` or `each`?

Comment: Just trying to loop through the comments

Comment: Is there an end corresponding to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're confused about how to use blocks.

```
in_msg.updateComments.each do |key, value|
   # code here...
end
```

OR

```
in_msg.updateComments.each {|key, value| code_here }
```

**Update**: now that you posted your data... looks like you have several nested hashes and arrays. I'd recommend finding a good tutorial on both ruby arrays and ruby hashes.

Comment: Or perhaps `.each`, depending on what the OP is actually trying to do.

Comment: Well the data comes in as a hash, I tried to loop through the comments in there hash. the comments are also a hash (I just updated the original question) so I was just trying to get the comments.

Comment: `each_pair` is equivalent to `each` for hashes, btw.

Answer (score 2):

First of all. Here is the link to [Hash object](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html). We don not need `map` method to iterate through hash. Iterations through Hash are done using `each`, `each_pair`, `each_key`, `each_value` methods. See the previously provided link for usages and syntax.

```
in_msg.updateComments.each do |key, value|
  p key #prints "values" string on first loop
  value.each do |k, v|
    p k #prints "comment", "person"
    p v #prints "Sweet", "{"siteStandardProfileRequest"=>{"url"=>"http://www.linkedin.com/profile?viewProfile=&key=23676551&authToken=FHXz&authType=name&trk=api*a140290*s148640*"}"
  end
end
```

Comment: `Hash` inherits from `Enumerable`, so *of course* it has a `map` method.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the syntax you're looking for is this:

```
in_msg.updateComments.map { |c| 
  c.each  do |comment| 
     # do stuff for each comment
  end
}
```